# How to solve this contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to solve this contour integral.I know that it could be evaluated using Cauchy's Theorem or by its residues and find that it is $0$, but I would like to solve it the old-fashioned way.
$$\int_C\frac{dz}{z^2-1}$$ where $C$ is the circle $|z|=2$.

I know that I need to parametrize, but I genuinely do not know how to parametrize something like this, as I am used to regular lines or easy curves.
What would be the best way to parametrize this?

Comment: I don't know how you would parameterise this other than using $\phi(t)=2e^{it}$

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same way, but I don¿t really know it that makes it much easier

Comment: When you use that substitution you can find an elementary antiderivative for the resulting integrand

Comment: Would the rewriting $$\frac{1}{z^2-1}=\frac{1}{z^2(1-z^{-2})}=z^{-2}(1+z^{-2}+z^{-4}+z^{-6}+\ldots)$$ be the old-fashioned way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma: [0,2\pi] \to \Bbb{C}$ be given by $\gamma(t):=2e^{it}$. Note that $\gamma$ parametrizes $|z|=2$. Then, 
$$
\int_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{z^2-1} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{2ie^{it}}{4e^{2it}-1}dt = \frac{1}{2}\left(\log(1 - 2 e^{i t}) - \log(1 + 2 e^{i t})\right)\mid_{t=0}^{2\pi} = 0
$$
This is the same answer you get if you use the Residue theorem:
$$
\int_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{z^2-1} = 2\pi i ( \textrm{Res}(f, 1) +  \textrm{Res}(f,- 1) )=  2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)=0
$$
where $f(z):=\frac{1}{z^2-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with $z=2e^{i\theta},$ for $0\le \theta\le 2\pi.$ Then
$$dz=2ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta, $$
and you write
$$\int_C\frac{dz}{z^2-1}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2ie^{i\theta}}{4e^{2i\theta}-1}\,d\theta. $$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: is there an easy way to solve it? I finally solved it, but  I had to separate the denominator by partial fractions, and then partial fraction one of them again and use substitution a few times, which seemed a lot harder than it should have been